# Delete multiple duplicate rows in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have multiple groups of duplicates in one table (3 records for one, 2 for another, etc) - multiple rows where more than 1 exists.

Below is what I came up with to delete them, but I have to run the script for however many duplicates there are:

```
set rowcount 1
delete from Table
where code in (
  select code from Table 
  group by code
  having (count(code) > 1)
)
set rowcount 0
```

This works well to a degree.  I need to run this for every group of duplicates, and then it only deletes 1 (which is all I need right now).

Comment: Which of the duplicates do you want to keep -- the first/lowest, or latest/maximum?  And for what version of SQL Server?

Comment: Either - max ID would work.  SQL Server 2000 (yea, I know)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: Thanks for the link, Martin - I was worried it was a possible dupe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a key column on the table, then you can use this to uniquely identify the "distinct" rows in your table.

Just use a sub query to identify a list of ID's for unique rows and then delete everything outside of this set. Something along the lines of.....

```
create table #TempTable
(
    ID int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    SomeData varchar(100) not null
)

insert into #TempTable(SomeData) values('someData1')
insert into #TempTable(SomeData) values('someData1')
insert into #TempTable(SomeData) values('someData2')
insert into #TempTable(SomeData) values('someData2')
insert into #TempTable(SomeData) values('someData2')
insert into #TempTable(SomeData) values('someData3')
insert into #TempTable(SomeData) values('someData4')

select * from #TempTable

--Records to be deleted
SELECT ID
FROM #TempTable
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    select MAX(ID)
    from #TempTable
    group by SomeData
)

--Delete them
DELETE
FROM #TempTable
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    select MAX(ID)
    from #TempTable
    group by SomeData
)

--Final Result Set
select * from #TempTable

drop table #TempTable;
```

Alternatively you could use a CTE for example:

```
WITH UniqueRecords AS
(
    select MAX(ID) AS ID
    from #TempTable
    group by SomeData
)
DELETE A
FROM #TempTable A
    LEFT outer join UniqueRecords B on
        A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Just noticed that the OP is on SQL Server 2000 anyway but it's possible to do this more efficiently with a CTE as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows/3822833#3822833

Answer (score 2):

It is frequently more efficient to copy unique rows into temporary table,
drop source table, rename back temporary table.

I reused the definition and data of  #TempTable, called here  as SrcTable instead, since it is impossible to rename temporary table into a regular one)

```
create table SrcTable
(
    ID int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    SomeData varchar(100) not null
)

insert into SrcTable(SomeData) values('someData1')
insert into SrcTable(SomeData) values('someData1')
insert into SrcTable(SomeData) values('someData2')
insert into SrcTable(SomeData) values('someData2')
insert into SrcTable(SomeData) values('someData2')
insert into SrcTable(SomeData) values('someData3')
insert into SrcTable(SomeData) values('someData4')
```

by John Sansom in [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917565/delete-multiple-duplicate-rows-in-table/3917611#3917611)

```
-- cloning "unique" part
SELECT * INTO TempTable 
FROM SrcTable --original table
WHERE id IN  
(SELECT MAX(id) AS ID
FROM SrcTable
GROUP BY SomeData);
GO;

DROP TABLE SrcTable
GO;

sys.sp_rename 'TempTable', 'SrcTable'
```

Comment: if you use this strategy, after renaming you should readd keys, constraints, identity values, indexes and relations

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to filter out duplicates

```
;WITH [CTE_DUPLICATES] AS 
(
SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SomeData ORDER BY SomeData)
FROM #TempTable
) 
DELETE FROM [CTE_DUPLICATES] WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: The OP for this question is on SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1    
DELETE Table    
FROM Table a    
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table b WHERE b.Code = a.Code ) > 1    
WHILE @@rowcount > 0    
  DELETE Table    
  FROM Table a    
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table b WHERE b.Code = a.Code ) > 1    
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

this will delete all duplicate rows, But you can add attributes if you want to compare according to them .